# Set initial values to lpVariable declared as lpVariable.dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, set, pulp

I need to assign the initial values to my lpVariables.
I declared them using lpVariable.dicts.

Is it possible to assign an initial value to them?

The code is like this:

```
temp_int = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

    # set problem variable
    prob = LpProblem("Supply_Chain", LpMinimize)
    
    # decision variables
    Qi_var = LpVariable.dicts("Qi_var", temp_int, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
    Wi_var = LpVariable.dicts("Wi", temp_int, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)
    Qai_var = LpVariable.dicts("Qai", temp_int, cat=LpInteger)
    Dip_1_var = LpVariable.dicts("Dip_i", temp_int, cat='Continuous')
    
    #constraints
    ....
    
    Qi_var.setInitialValue(0)
    Wi_var.setInitialValue(0)
    Qai_var.setInitialValue(0)
    Dip_1_var.setInitialValue(0)
    
    prob.solve(solver=PULP_CBC_CMD())
```

The output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\davide.tamagnini.con\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.1\scratches\example.py", line 80, in <module>
    Qi_var.setInitialValue(0)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'setInitialValue'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if giving initial values will help you. But if you really want to try you need to iterate over all variables in the dictionary, i.e., do:

```
for v in Qi_var.values():
    v.setInitialValue(0)
```